# .NET MVC and securely passing data between pages

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, persistence

a little background info first. I have been using Web Forms for most of my career and have recently become interested in .NET MVC. I realize that it is intended to be stateless, however, I don't understand how it is completely feasible. In a forms application, the user authenticates and I return a user ID and some roles which are then placed in that users session. When I need them, all I have to do is pull it out of session and I have it. From what I have read, session and MVC are mutually exclusive. I've read that one can use TempData  to pass values but it only persists for one page visit and then its gone. Is there a standard way that data can be "persisted" on an MVC site other than adding redundant code to every controller where I want to pass the data?

Answer (score 4):

I think there might be some confusion in terms here.  What's truly stateless here is the HTTP protocol.  ASP.NET WebForms was a technology developed to try and build a framework that "worked around" the statelessness of HTTP, and create a stateful web based application framework.  That is why you see things in WebForms such as ViewState, which essentially carries the state of the application along the pipe.

ASP.NET MVC came along and took a different approach.  It embraces the statelessness of HTTP.  That's why there's no ViewState in MVC.

However, that does not mean that you are no longer interacting with stateful entities.  The client machine (a browser for instance) is a stateful application, just as the server running the server side code (in this case IIS or whatever) is stateful as well.

Therefore, things that are on the server side are still stateful (like Session, Application, Cache), and you can still use them.  Also, the client-side is stateful as well, which is why client-side scripting has become so powerful in recent years; people trying to take full advantage of the statefullness of the browser.

Answer (score 2):

The ASP.NET MVC Framework is built upon the ASP.NET framework and as such, you can use Session state in ASP.NET MVC:

```
Session["MyVar"] = "SomeValue";
```